# How to create a domain and sub domain

Tags: domain, subdomain, iis-7.5

I wanna know how to create a domain and sub domain(s) in IIS 7.5/3 I need to make it on my own without a Plesk or any other control panel.

I do have a domain I will sync it to my server using "A record" how to add a domain at IIS to manage folders..?

Answer (score 0):

I put together a couple videos that will hopefully answer this for you.

- [DNS related](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/01/08/understanding-dns-zone-records-web-pro-series-week-2.aspx)
- [Understanding site bindings](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/01/29/understanding-iis-bindings.aspx)

They are about 10 minutes each so they are meant to allow you to get up to speed quickly without a large time investment.

One thing to note is that you likely want 2+ sites.  One for the domain and one for each site.  Host headers will bind to each site instance.